# Wrong librarys opened when building

Tags: c, mingw, codeblocks

I'm using codeblocks with mingw for C, and when I try to include stdio and build it will open up another page with the stddef source code instead and give a ton of errors, more than 50.

Comment: Your question is too vague. Which code are you building (have you tried with a minimal code? which code?)? What are your errors exactly (the first few errors should tell us a lot already)?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.